# Fetch Facebook friends information like email id and phone number from android app version 4.4

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I am able to fetch my Facebook friends list using FB library. But the email field or phone number field retrieved is always null.

I understand that this is privacy concern .But if my friend has changed all contact information to public ,even then it returns null.

Samsung phones are able to do it . Just wondering if I am missing anything in API call.

Any help highly appreciated.
Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- friend permissions have been removed with v2.0, but phone number and email was never possible to get from friends
- You can get the email of the authorized user with the `email` permission

More information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog